# jsonify bolt statementresult

Tags: python, neo4j

My first question here!

I am developing webservices using python and flask. Neo4j is my backend which I would like to APIfy.

I run a match query on the graph db and wants to return a json object. Below is the code.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

app = Flask(__name__)

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, pass))

@app.route('/')
def com_relations():
    with driver.session() as session:
        with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
            return jsonify(tx.run("MATCH (company:Company)-[]->(c) where c.name is not null "
                             "RETURN company.name, c.name"))

        session.close()
```

But I get an error while running the app.

```
TypeError: Object of type 'BoltStatementResult' is not JSON serializable
```

I understand the error and I would like to know how to jsonify my statement result from neo4j. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the result of the query is an [`StatementResult object`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/1.5-preview/session.html#neo4j.v1.StatementResult), which can not be "serialized". So you need to first prepare the result like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

app = Flask(__name__)

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, pass))

@app.route('/')
def com_relations():
    with driver.session() as session:
        with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
            results = (tx.run("MATCH (company:Company)-[]->(c) where c.name is not null"
                              "RETURN company.name, c.name"))    
        session.close()
        records = []
        for record in results:
            records.append({"company.name": record["company.name"],
                            "name": record["c.name"]})
        return jsonify(records)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty much I was using as an alternate. I had another thought if there are other methods to serialize a statementResult object... Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

you can also change the query just to get the JSON format.

```
"MATCH (company:Company)-[]->(c) where c.name is not null RETURN COLLECT({company:company.name, name:c.name}) AS jsonOutput"
```